# Flex Grow until specific max-height inside of a vertically centered div with min-height 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need a centered box inside a 100vh min-height container with a min-height of 100% and a max-height of let's say 600px. thats pretty easy so far. but in my centered box i have 3 other elements (title, content and footer). the content part has to grow until all available space is reached (in this case it's the max-height of the parent minus the title and gg part).

is this possible with flexbox?

here is a short scribble:
[image]

I also tried i by myself, but i run into problems as soon as i enter a minheight of 100% istead of a pixel value to the item div.
any idea how i can fix this and can work with min-height 100%?

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.wrapper {
  background: rgba(red, 0.3);
  display:flex;
  min-height:100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  //flex-direction:column;
  
  .wrapper-inner {
    padding:20px;
    max-width:80%;
    min-height:100%;
    //max-height: 500px;
    background:#fff;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    background: rgba(green, 0.2);
    
  }
  .item {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    max-height:600px;
    background:#fff;
  }
  
  .titel,
  .content,
  .footer {
    padding:10px;
    background: rgba(#000, 0.2);
    margin-bottom:10px;
  }
  .content {
   flex-grow:1;
  }
  
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
    <div class="item">


      <div class="titel">Titel here...</div>
      <div class="content">
        content goes here. this box has to grow until the space is filled.
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
      <div class="footer">gg</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zg3kLe70/14/

**EDIT:** And here the design:
The White Box has to fill the available max-height space.
[image]

**EDIT2:** I'm getting closer and closer :) newest fiddel seems to work well in chrome, firefox, edge and safari. but in IE10/11 the content is not centered. i think it's a problem with the min-height:100 vh...
https://jsfiddle.net/zg3kLe70/26/

Thank you,
Marco

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: just chrome for dev. but it has to work in ie11+, ff, chrome and safari.

Comment: do you need that many wrappers ?

Comment: I assume as you are using flex you are dealing with modern browsers. 

Why not use transform: translate(-50%,-50%) strategy described in a great article by css-tricks. 
https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/

Set fixed height for "header div" a fixed height for "footer div" and the element should grow till max height is reached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use less wrappers. 
For a single box to be at center *(body is the wrapper-inner)*:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: lightblue;
}

body {
  max-height: 600px;
  width: 80%;
  border: solid;
  margin: auto;
  background: crimson;
  color: white;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  background: maroon;
  /* overflow:auto; */
  /* recommended*/
}

body>* {
  padding: 3vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>header any height</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <p>should it be scrolling when needed</p>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>footer any height</p>
</footer>
```

For a few boxes stacking at 100vh and a centered box, an extra wrapper to set the 100% height is  needed and an inner wrapper to set the *(max-)*height.  *(body  holds a few wrapper)*

*first box might the one you look for in the snippet below, growing from its content untill it reaches max-height set)*

```css
html, body , .wrapper, .wrapper-inner{
  height:100%;
}
.wrapper, .wrapper-inner {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
}
.wrapper-inner {
  max-height:600px;
  border:solid;
  background:crimson;
  color:white;
}
main {
  flex:1;
  background:maroon;
   overflow:auto; /* recommended*/
}
.wrapper:first-of-type .wrapper-inner {
height:auto;
}

.wrapper-inner > * {
  padding:3vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
  <header><h1>header any height</h1></header>
<main> <p>first box will grow up 600px max</p> </main>
<footer><p>footer any height</p></footer></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
  <header><h1>header any height</h1></header>
<main> <p>should it be scrolling when needed</p> </main>
<footer><p>footer any height</p></footer></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
  <header><h1>header any height</h1></header>
<main> <p>should it be scrolling when needed</p> </main>
<footer><p>footer any height</p></footer></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. and how can i achieve, that the content already uses the whole space, even if there is not enaugh content to fill it to max-height? i added a new image in my first post. the white area in the middle needs to fill the available space until max-height is reached.

Comment: haaa, my newest version is working now :) it scales the right way in all browsers expect IE10+11. Any ideas how to fix this IE11 flexbug?

https://jsfiddle.net/zg3kLe70/26/

Comment: for IE to set a min-height,(100vh) on a flex container, the parent has to be a flex container too ... it is a known bug . the parent of wrapper is body so you need  `body {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
}`  https://jsfiddle.net/zg3kLe70/28/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just found out, how it works :)

First of all, I need a flex-basis of 100% for the content div. Just min-width is not enough. Second, I removed all unnecessary wrappers. What I ended up is really simple but effective:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.wrapper {
  background: rgba(red, 0.3);
  display:flex;
  margin:0 auto;
  min-height:100vh;
  width:80%;
  
  .item {
    display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-basis: 100%;
 background: rgba(green, 0.3);
 justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .titel,
  .content,
  .footer {
    padding:10px;
    background: rgba(#000, 0.2);
    margin-bottom:10px;
  }
  .content {
   flex-grow:1;
   flex-basis:100%;
   max-height:300px;
   min-height:100px;
  }

  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="titel">Titel here...</div>
      <div class="content">
          content goes here. this box has to grow until the space is filled
      </div>
      <div class="footer">footer here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zg3kLe70/33/

Thanks!

Comment: of course he did ;) chill dude, i already upvoted his answer :)

Comment: I commented as you after 11 hours still haven't done either, hence thought you were to leave it as is ... great you didn't :) ... and I removed my downvote